# inline block divs with fixed height and width, uneven

Tags: html, css

I want all three boxes to be at the same level, you'll see how box 2 is below box 1 and 2 because it has less content in it than the other boxes, but there has to be some style I am missing to be make each div display at the same level (visually speaking) regardless of the content in it.

http://jsfiddle.net/bkmorse/519xzvou/

css

```
.container {
    width: 470px;
    border:1px solid purple;
    height: 210px;
}

.box {
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    border:1px solid red;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <h1>Box 1</h1>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
        <h1>Box 2</h1>
    </div>    
    <div class="box">
        <h1>Box 3</h1>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding `.box { vertical-align: top; }` seem that works: http://jsfiddle.net/519xzvou/1/

Comment: alternatively you could just `float` the `box`es

Answer (score 4, accepted):

apply the style [`vertical-align:top` to `.box`](http://jsfiddle.net/519xzvou/1/) in your stylesheet

Answer (score 2):

Making them display like `table-cell` also fit their heights and placement automatically:

http://jsfiddle.net/519xzvou/2/

```
.box {
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    border:1px solid red;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use CSS 3 property in parent class
display:-webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;

[jsfiddle][1]

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/519xzvou/4/
```